# Primefaces: XML5635: An XML declaration is only allowed at the beginning of the file

Tags: java, xml, internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces

After migrating to PF 5.0, on IE navigation does not work after clicking on p:commandlink or p:commandButton new page is not loaded and instead of that there is message on console:
XML5635: An XML declaration is only allowed at the beginning of the file. Line: 1, Column 18

This is valid only on IE on Firefox chrome it works fine.

first file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

        <h:head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
            <title>.... </title>

            <meta name="Description" content="......"/>
            <meta name="AUTHOR" content="..."/>

            <meta name="KEYWORDS" content="....."/>

    <h:outputText 
        value="&lt;!--[if !IE]&gt; --&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot; href=&quot;#{sessionBean.getUrlPrefix()}html/style.css&quot; /&gt; &lt;!-- &lt;![endif]--&gt;"
        escape="false" />


    <h:outputText 
        value="&lt;!--[if IE ]&gt;&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; href=&quot;#{sessionBean.getUrlPrefix()}html/style-ie.css&quot; /&gt; &lt;![endif]--&gt;"
        escape="false" />

        </h:head>

        <h:body>

            <div id="top">
                <ui:insert name="header">
                    <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>
                </ui:insert>
                <div id="CONTENT"><div id="TRESC">
                        <ui:insert name="leftBar">
                            <ui:include src="leftbar.xhtml"/>
                        </ui:insert>
                        <div style="width: 700px; float: left;">
                            <f:metadata>
                                <f:viewParam name="CalendarSet" value="#{sessionBean.calendarSet}" />
                            </f:metadata>
                            <h1 style=" text-align: center; font-size: 30px;">#{tr['chooseCalendarType']}</h1>

                            <p:accordionPanel   multiple="true">
                                <p:tab title="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.typeT1Name}" rendered="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.isActiveT1()}">
                                    <h:form>
                                        <p:dataGrid value="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.calendariumT1}" var="calendarium" columns="2"   >

                                            <p:panel >

                                                <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="text-align:center;"  >
                                                    <p:commandLink action="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.calendariumChosen(calendarium.id)}">
                                                        <p:graphicImage width="250" id="image_num"  value="#{calendarium.imageUrl}" />
                                                    </p:commandLink>
                                                    <p:tooltip  style="background: grey; color:white;" for="image_num"  showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
                                                        <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{calendarium.name}"/>
                                                    </p:tooltip>

                                                    <p:commandButton action="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.calendariumChosen(calendarium.id)}" value="#{tr['choose']}"/>
                                                </h:panelGrid> 

                                            </p:panel>

                                        </p:dataGrid>
                                    </h:form>
                                </p:tab>
                                <p:tab title="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.typeT2Name}" rendered="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.isActiveT2()}">
                                    <h:form>
                                        <p:dataGrid  style="border: none;" value="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.calendariumT2}" var="calendarium" columns="2"   >

                                            <p:panel style="width: 320px; text-align:center;" >

                                                <h:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="backgroudless" style="text-align:center;"  >
                                                    <p:commandLink action="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.calendariumChosen(calendarium.id)}">
                                                        <p:graphicImage width="250" id="image_num"  value="#{calendarium.imageUrl}" />
                                                    </p:commandLink>

                                                    <p:commandButton action="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.calendariumChosen(calendarium.id)}" value="#{tr['choose']}"/>

                                                </h:panelGrid> 

                                            </p:panel>

                                        </p:dataGrid>
                                    </h:form>
                                </p:tab>   
                                <p:tab title="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.typeT3Name}" rendered="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.isActiveT3()}">
                                    <h:form>
                                        <p:dataGrid styleClass="backgroudless" style="border: none;" value="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.calendariumT3}" var="calendarium" columns="2"   >

                                            <p:panel styleClass="backgroudless" style="width: 320px; text-align:center;" >

                                                <h:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="backgroudless" style="text-align:center;"  >
                                                    <p:commandLink action="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.calendariumChosen(calendarium.id)}">
                                                        <p:graphicImage width="250" id="image_num"  value="#{calendarium.imageUrl}" />
                                                    </p:commandLink>

                                                    <p:commandButton action="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.calendariumChosen(calendarium.id)}" value="#{tr['choose']}"/> 

                                                </h:panelGrid> 

                                            </p:panel>

                                        </p:dataGrid>
                                    </h:form>
                                </p:tab>    
                                <p:tab title="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.typeT4Name}" rendered="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.isActiveT4()}">
                                    <h:form>
                                        <p:dataGrid styleClass="backgroudless" style="border: none;" value="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.calendariumT4}" var="calendarium" columns="2"   >

                                            <p:panel styleClass="backgroudless" style="width: 320px; text-align:center;" >

                                                <h:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="backgroudless" style="text-align:center;"  >
                                                    <p:commandLink action="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.calendariumChosen(calendarium.id)}">
                                                        <p:graphicImage width="250" id="image_num"  value="#{calendarium.imageUrl}" />
                                                    </p:commandLink>

                                                    <p:commandButton action="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.calendariumChosen(calendarium.id)}" value="#{tr['choose']}"/>
                                                </h:panelGrid> 

                                            </p:panel>

                                        </p:dataGrid>
                                    </h:form>
                                </p:tab>                             
                                 <p:tab title="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.typeT5Name}" rendered="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.isActiveT5()}">
                                    <h:form>
                                        <p:dataGrid styleClass="backgroudless" style="border: none;" value="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.calendariumT5}" var="calendarium" columns="2"   >

                                            <p:panel styleClass="backgroudless" style="width: 320px; text-align:center;" >

                                                <h:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="backgroudless" style="text-align:center;"  >
                                                    <p:commandLink action="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.calendariumChosen(calendarium.id)}">
                                                        <p:graphicImage width="250" id="image_num"  value="#{calendarium.imageUrl}" />
                                                    </p:commandLink>

                                                    <p:commandButton action="#{calendarTypesHandlingBean.calendariumChosen(calendarium.id)}" value="#{tr['choose']}"/>
                                                </h:panelGrid> 

                                            </p:panel>

                                        </p:dataGrid>
                                    </h:form>
                                </p:tab>       

                            </p:accordionPanel>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ui:insert name="footer">
                        <ui:include src="footer.xhtml"/>
                    </ui:insert>
                </div></div>

        </h:body>
    </html>
```

and the second:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

        <h:head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
            <title>...</title>

            <meta name="Description" content="..."/>
            <meta name="AUTHOR" content="..."/>

            <meta name="KEYWORDS" content="..."/>
    <h:outputText 
        value="&lt;!--[if !IE]&gt; --&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot; href=&quot;#{sessionBean.getUrlPrefix()}html/style.css&quot; /&gt; &lt;!-- &lt;![endif]--&gt;"
        escape="false" />


    <h:outputText 
        value="&lt;!--[if IE ]&gt;&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; href=&quot;#{sessionBean.getUrlPrefix()}html/style-ie.css&quot; /&gt; &lt;![endif]--&gt;"
        escape="false" />


        </h:head>

        <h:body>
            <div id="top">
                <ui:insert name="header">
                    <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>
                </ui:insert>
                <div id="CONTENT"><div id="TRESC">
                        <ui:insert name="leftBar">
                            <ui:include src="leftbar.xhtml"/>
                        </ui:insert>

            <div style="float: left;width: 730px;">
                  <h1 style=" text-align: center; font-size: 30px;">#{tr['chooseCalendarBackground']}</h1>
                  <h:form>
                <p:dataGrid columns="3"  style=" border-style: none;" value="#{backgroundSelectorBean.backgrounds}" var="item" >

            <p:panel style="text-align:center; width: 220px; "  >
                <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%; border: 0; text-align: center;"  >
                    <p:commandLink action="#{backgroundSelectorBean.selectedBackground(item.backgroundId, item.backgroundPatch)}">
                    <p:graphicImage width="200" id="image_num" value="#{item.backgroundThumbURL}" />
                    </p:commandLink>
                    <p:commandButton action="#{backgroundSelectorBean.selectedBackground(item.backgroundId, item.backgroundPatch)}" value="#{tr['choose']}" />  

                </h:panelGrid> 
            </p:panel>

        </p:dataGrid>
                      </h:form>
                     <p:button outcome="back" value="#{tr['back']}">  
                    </p:button>
                </div>

                    </div>
                                    <ui:insert name="footer">
                        <ui:include src="footer.xhtml"/>
                    </ui:insert>
                </div></div>
            </h:body>
    </html>
```

I would be grateful for help.

Comment: check if you have white-spaces in the beginning of the second file... and what IE version ?

Comment: There are no white spaces I've already checked that, it was tested on IE 10 and 11 and it shows on both versions.

Comment: Check the response headers for Content-Type, what is it ?

Comment: In header there is context-type: "text/xml;charset=UTF-8"

Comment: maybe this is the reason, usually it's `Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: when I load first page there is text/html when loading second (it can be seen only on firefox, not IE) there is text/xml but on IE it cannot be seen, there is not second text document loaded on IE

Comment: anyway, the question is how to change it? the headers on both files are the same...

Comment: I can't predict what might cause this without some code, place your buttons or links and if you have managedBeans.

Comment: This error may occur if you have anything like `<?xml ?>` in any other place in your code. Be aware of static inclusion of XML files which may include the XML declaration. Check your generated source code. It will fail in browsers that treat your code as XHTML (not HTML).

Comment: I have no [link] <?xml[link] marks in the code the code of the page:

Comment: I've added code for 2 xml files hope you can find somethig is wrong there